# I am getting permissinon error during creation of VM

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, google-developers-console

this is the error "You don't have permission to view the instances in this project"

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a TL;DR case, I advise you to read the public documentation of [IAM for Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/iam). Granting the roles/compute.instanceAdmin.v1  role to your account should fix your issue